# Parallel Stream with Progressmonitor opens multiple dialogs

Tags: java, swing, java-stream, progressmonitor

I have a strange behavior I cannot explain.

Please have a look at this minimal example:

```
public class ParallelStreamProgressMonitor
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        List<Integer> belege = IntStream.range(1, 100).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
        final ProgressMonitor pm = new ProgressMonitor(null, "Initialmessage", "Initial Note", 0, belege.size());
        pm.setMillisToDecideToPopup(0);
        pm.setMillisToPopup(0);
        pm.setMaximum(belege.size());
        pm.setNote("Now I am working");
        AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();
        belege.stream().parallel().forEach(b ->
        {
            System.out.println(b);
            pm.setProgress(counter.getAndIncrement());
            try
            {
                //something time consuming ...
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e)
            {
                // ignore
            }
        });
    }
}
```

When executing this, you'd normally expect that a ProgressMonitor will come up and show the progress of the execution.

But this is how it really looks like:
[image: Screenshot]

It seems that for every parallel stream executions there is one ProgressMonitor instance extra showing up.

Is there a reason for this? How can I achieve that only one dialog shows up and shows the progress?

Comment: Does anything in the documentation of `ProgressMonitor` say that it was safe to be used from different threads?

Comment: I couldn't find anything about this. But I think I found a solution ... see edit

Comment: Don’t post solutions in the question. That’s what the Answers section is for. Besides that, accessing Swing components from a different thread with `synchronized` still doesn’t conform to Swing’s threading policy. It may happen to work one time, but is not guaranteed to continue to work. Besides that, it’s inefficient.

Comment: Thanks, you are right. I deleted it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider [Swing's Threading Policy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/package-summary.html#threading):

> In general Swing is not thread safe. All Swing components and related classes, unless otherwise documented, must be accessed on the event dispatching thread.

This implies that you have to study [`ProgressMonitor`’s documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/ProgressMonitor.html) to find out whether “unless otherwise documented” applies, but since there’s no other threading policy, there’s nothing to cite here.

One way to perform an action in the Event Dispatch Thread is to encapsulate it in a `Runnable` and use [`invokeLater(Runnable)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater-java.lang.Runnable-), but when doing it for sending different progress states from an unknown number of worker threads they may arrive in the wrong order and it would also be quite inefficient. Since you already have an `AtomicInteger`, the better option is to use a [Swing `Timer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html):

```java
public class ParallelStreamProgressMonitor
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        List<Integer> belege
            = IntStream.range(1, 100).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
        final ProgressMonitor pm = new ProgressMonitor(
                null, "Initialmessage", "Initial Note", 0, belege.size());
        pm.setMillisToDecideToPopup(0);
        pm.setMillisToPopup(0);
        pm.setMaximum(belege.size());
        pm.setNote("Now I am working");
        AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();
        Timer timer = new Timer(250, ev -> pm.setProgress(counter.get()));
        timer.start();
        belege.stream().parallel().forEach(b ->
        {
            System.out.println(b);
            counter.getAndIncrement();
            //simulate something time consuming ...
            LockSupport.parkNanos(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toNanos(1000));
        });
        timer.stop();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a real need to use parallel processing? If not replace  `belege.stream().parallel().forEach(b ->` with  `belege.stream().forEach(b ->`, it should solve your problem.

A parallel execution will involve more threads, hence multiple calls to the progress monitor will be made from different contexts. Each thread will show one progress UI, and eventually you'll have more than one of that. So if you do not have a real reason to use parallel execution go for sequential one.

Comment: Yes, in my case I have a very large collection to be processed (and it can be processed parallel).